# eclipse project not importing the jar packages in local Maven repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

I am facing a problem in setting my eclipse project.
The problem is whenever I am creating a new project and import the code.Eclipse is not resolving the packages which are present in the jar files which are present in the C;/..../user/.m2/repository.

Hence it's giving a lot of compilation errors until I add all the required jar files manually in the build-path by going to "Add External Jars"

I saw that M2_REPO is present in my Eclipse classpath.But still it is not resolving the packages.
Please suggest how this problem can be resolved.

Gaurav

Comment: Do you have the m2eclipse plugin installed? What version? Is this a WTP project?

Comment: Hi Rob,Thanks for replying.I have m2eclipse version 0.12.1.20110112-1712 installed.Its not a WTP project.I am working on Dspace open-source software.

Comment: Hi,I checked and found that the .classpath file for my project has got an entry for Maven      <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>  But still eclipse is not able to import the .m2/repo jars

Comment: If you are using Indigo than M2_REPO is wrong..you have to use m2e instead of m2eclipse...

Answer (score 4):

I've been having a similar error in Eclipse on OSX. In Eclipse on the Mac, there is no "Maven" entry when you right-click on a project in the explorer.

However!

I just discovered that if I right click and then click "Validate", it suddenly magically resolves all the dependencies. No idea why, but maybe this will help.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue on Eclipse Kepler EE which comes prebuilt with m2e, I finally got it working by doing the following on each project:

- Right click on the Project
- Select Properties
- Select Maven
- Uncheck the option that says: Resolve Dependencies from Workspace projects

It should pop up with a box that says Maven setting has changed. Do you want to update project configuration. Click Yes to this.

To confirm:

- Right click on the project
- Select Properties
- Select Java Build Path
- Check the Libraries tab under Maven dependencies that all the jar you
  expected are now there.

Comment: I did this but it didn't change anything. The same compilation errors remain even after a clean. Eclipse is still not seeing any jar in the Maven Dependencies even though it's in the build path. Why?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 1):

close your project, and remove your project settings files: .project, .classpath, .settings/. Then re-import this project. It will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Though this answer is late. But it can help the future audience.

You can give it a try using Project(Right-Click) -> Maven -> Update Project. To select all or the number of projects you want to update.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put all needed dependencies in the pom.xml? Even if the Jars are already in your local repository, each project needs its dependencies mentioned in the pom.xml to resolve the dependencies. If you do that, m2eclipse will automatically resolve the build path.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Yes,the dependecies are present in the pom.xml file.I was using the version from dspace's git repo but checked it again to verify.I have tried almost everything I could find on the net but still the problem persists

Comment: Do you see the "Maven Dependencies" container entry in your projects in the Package Explorer? If not, open the pom.xml and look for an error.

Comment: hi,"Maven Dependencies" container entry is not present in Package explorer.But my project is getting built properly via commandline.I have looked at the pom.xml as it is from stable trunk of Dspace,it doesn't have error.

Comment: Is there any error in the Problems view? Generally, if the Maven Dependencies container isn't present, m2eclipse has problems to find a dependency or something like that.

Comment: yeah.Problems view is showing compilation errors mostly about failing to resolve type.But the "mavn package" is running successfully even from within the Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility.  Are you running Eclipse using JDK or JRE - the default is JRE.  You will see a warning in Eclipse console, if so.

maven eclipse plugin will not work correctly unless run with JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem.  The JDK was there, the problems view was set to Show All, and yet there were hundreds of unresolved type errors.  Not even Refresh (F5) would work.

In the Project|Properties|Java Build Path|Libraries window I was seeing only the JRE System Library, but not the desired "Maven Dependencies" entry.  And "Maven Dependencies" was also missing from the Package Explorer view as well.

I finally fixed this by right clicking on the project in the Package Explorer, selecting Maven from the menu, then selecting "Update Project Configuration."  This added "Maven Dependencies" and all the errors went away.

This was nice because prior to this fix I had to treat Eclipse like a dumb editor and run `mvn compile` on the commandline to find errors.