# Maven/Subeclipse imports cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, subclipse

Normally a command-line person, I've been tasked with coming up with a standard Eclipse IDE configuration.

**Steps leading up to the problem**

Using Eclipse Kepler Java Enterprise Edition, I added Subclipse (and the m2e/Subclipse connector and JavaHL).

I created a new project Maven from SCM project

That created a generic project, so I right-clicked on my project and converted it to a Java facet.

**The problem**

All my external dependencies show up as red X's on the import lines. E.g. for Jackson, the line import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*; shows up as an error "The import com.fasterxml cannot be resolved".

**What I have tried**

I have verified that M2_REPO is properly defined in Windows->Preferences->Java->Build Path->Classpath Variables (it was already defined -- I didn't have to add it -- and it was set to the correct directory /home//.m2/repository)

As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21706236/1624911 I tried unchecking Project->Properties->Maven->Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects

As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8683126/1624911 I tried right-clicking my project and selecting Validate

As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6779764/1624911 I tried right-clicking my project and selecting Maven->Update Project

Comment: Are you using the embedded maven, or an external one?

Comment: I am using the m2e that came with Eclipse Kepler Java Enterprise Edition. I assume it's using the Maven 3.2.1 that I previously installed (and put in PATH and created M2_HOME). Does Kepler come with a full Maven? If so, perhaps I should try uninstalling Eclipse and Maven and reinstalling Eclipse.

Comment: Kepler comes with an embedded install of maven 3.0.4.  Even if you have another maven installed and set up, eclipse won't use it unless you make it the default in Preferences > Maven > Installations.

Comment: Are the .project and .classpath files checked in? If yes you should use 'import project from SCM'. If not -> check them in after you have everything set up. Is This a maven project? right click on project -> Configure -> Convert to Maven project. If it is, try updating the maven configuration: 'right click -> Maven -> Update project'. And last: Try right click -> run as -> maven build and the check the console for errors like "could not download xxx.jar"

Comment: I tried reinstalling on a clean CentOS with no Maven pre-installed, and it's the same symptoms. I'll probably try Juno next.